# How to get data from another Java class which has a big signature constructor, without polluting the code?

Tags: java

I'm designing a small project, which simplifying things, looks like this

First I have a class that load data from a file:

```
public class Data{
    //private variables here
    public Input(File file, other parameters..){
       //load files
    }
    // getters for private variables here
 }
```

Then I have an algorithm class that should use the data loaded on the class Data:

```
public boolean Algorithm {
    public boolean foo {
        //initialize something
        return recursiveAlgo(//parameters that would come from the Data class);
    }
    public boolean recursiveAlgo(//parameters..){
        return something;
    }
}
```

The problem I want to solve is this:
I would like to use the data loaded in class Data through de getters, but without using the constructor: `Input input = new Input(File file, other parameters)` because it has a lot of parameters and those would have to go through the recursive calls later, causing them to have a big signature.
How can I access the data stored in Data class, without polluting my Algorithm class?

I would like to have something like this:

```
public boolean Algorithm {
    //Input input = new Input(File file, other parameters..); >not doing this<
    //Input input = new Input(); >maybe something like this<
    int row = input.getRow();
    int col = input.getCol();
    // so on..
    public boolean foo {
        //initialize something
        return recursiveAlgo(//parameters that would come from the Data class);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just pass the Data object to the Algorithm constructor or to Algorithm#foo()?

Comment: What is `Input` constructor in class `Data`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use builder design pattern to avoid passing too many parameters in the constructor.
It is used when we have too many arguments to send in constructor & it's hard to maintain order. A snippet of the template can be seen below. Hope it may give you proper insight. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y0sR.png